# Regex in python for not matching word

Tags: java, python, regex, review

I am reviewing java code and there are so many classes to check, I made a regex 
to find a method written in java that doesn't close IO stream within finally block.

`(?s)(?<=public|private|protected).(?<!finally).*?.close\(\)\;`

For some reason this doesn't work and it matches even those methods that has finally block, so below is found too

```
public testMethod(){
   InputStream stream = .....
   try{ 
     //do something
   } finally {
      if(stream != null){
         stream.close();
      }
   }
}
```

While only below should be matched

```
public testMethod(){
   InputStream stream = .....
   //do something
   if(stream != null){
     stream.close();
  }
}
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: A method in Java can just start without `(public|private|protected)` also

Comment: Thanks for replying, but lets assume our coders used access modifiers for all methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should probably be : `(?s)(?<=public|private|protected)((?!finally).)*close\(\)\;`. Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cI2wY0/1).

**Explanation** : `((?!finally).)*` verify that the rest of the string does not contain `finally`.

**Note** : in order to cover all cases, you might also want to check if the `close()` is actually inside the block of the finally. You can do it with an expression like `(?s)(?<=public|private|protected)((?!finally[^}]*close\(\)\;).)*close\(\)\;`.

Comment: Works perfect thanks, about close inside finally block, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: @Dwarf_Ostrich No problem. However [you should avoid to use comment for this purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)